# Mongoose create not inserting full data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I'm trying to build a NextJS app integrated with mongodb atlas. I'm using mongoose to create models and perform database operations.

I have a model created as follows:

```
import { Schema, model, models } from 'mongoose';

export interface IUser {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    bio?: string;
    city?: string;
    country?: string;
    technologies?: string[];
    website?: string;
    profileImageUrl?: string;
}

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: false,
        required: [true, 'Name is required.'],
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Email is required.'],
    },
    bio: {
        type: String,
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
    },
    country: {
        type: String,
    },
    technologies: {
        type: [String],
    },
    website: {
        type: String,
    },
    profileImageUrl: {
        type: String,
    },
});

const User = models.User || model('User', UserSchema);

export default User;
```

I'm trying to do a basic insert with this:

```
const user: IUser = {
    name: 'test',
    email: 'test',
    bio: 'test',
    city: 'test',
    country: 'test',
    technologies: ['test', 'test2'],
    website: 'test',
    profileImageUrl: 'test',
};

console.log('user', user);
const userRet = await User.create(user);
console.log('userRet', userRet);
```

The insert is successful, but the profileImageUrl is missing.
Here's the console.log for `user` and `userRet`:

```
user {
  name: 'test',
  email: 'test',
  bio: 'test',
  city: 'test',
  country: 'test',
  technologies: [ 'test', 'test2' ],
  website: 'test',
  profileImageUrl: 'test'
}
userRet {
  name: 'test',
  email: 'test',
  bio: 'test',
  city: 'test',
  country: 'test',
  technologies: [ 'test', 'test2' ],
  website: 'test',
  _id: new ObjectId("646d0295bf540792b632f051"),
  __v: 0
}
```

As you can see, the return value of the insert (or the database entry) is missing profileImageUrl. Even if I alter the schema and add other fields, the fields are all ignored. There are no error or logs anywhere I can access. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you try `const retrievedUser = await User.findById(userRet._id);
console.log('Retrieved user', retrievedUser);`?

Comment: Looks like it's the same (missing profileImageUrl):
`Retrieved user {
  _id: new ObjectId("646d35acbf540792b632f05f"),
  name: 'test',
  email: 'test',
  bio: 'test',
  city: 'test',
  country: 'test',
  technologies: [ 'test', 'test2' ],
  website: 'test',
  __v: 0
}
`